# VSCODE snippet for creating new C# class with namespace declaration

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

For now we are able to create only new `file` or `folder`. And it's very annoying to write namespaces each time you create class declaration.

But is it possible to create new C# class file with auto generated appropriate namespaces inside? Or maybe some snippet there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's currently not possible. You have no possibility to retrieve the current filename, directory or other information in a snippet declaration file for Visual Studio Code.

You could create a snippet that lets you enter a namespace and a class name. But I guess this wouldn't help you so much. Nevertheless it'd look like this:

```
 "Namespace and class": {
    "prefix": "namespaceAndClass",
    "body": [
        "namespace $1",
        "{",
        "   class $2",
        "   {",
        "",
        "   }",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Create a namespace block with a class"
 }
```

In case you **really** want a snippet that fills in the correct namespace and class name based on the file path you could have a look at the [OmniSharp project](http://www.omnisharp.net/). This can give you an idea on how to improve the csharp-o extension in order to provide the correct data as a suggestion from within the plugin.
But I think this is a much bigger task then typing namespace and class on your own.

Answer (score 8):

[This extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jchannon.csharpextensions) provides a context menu button to add a new class, which will auto populate the namespace.

Visual Studio Code has changed a bit since the last answer. It now provides the variable `TM_DIRECTORY` in snippets, but this is an absolute path. I've submitted [an enhancement request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37570) to provide a relative path that could be transformed to a namespace. But honestly, I think the above extension satisfies my needs (and the context menu is a plus)

Comment: The extension is now: ***** PROJECT NO LONGER UNDER DEVELOPMENT *****.

Comment: For more extensions providing the Context menu button solution, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759776/11627521).

Answer (score 5):

I have found these extensions that provide create C# class context menu option:

- [VS Sharper for C#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eservice-online.vs-sharper)
- [C# helper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=roadsidejesus.csharp-helper)
- [C# Template Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Mavusi.csharpextensions)
- [HelloVS - C# new file](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pampas93.hellovs)

Answer (score 4):

A moderately dirty solution with the current variable and regex system of vscode is the following:

Assuming that your have all your projects in **/your/projects/directory/**

So project #1 is in /your/projects/directory/Project1/
And project #2 is in /your/projects/directory/Project2/
etc.

The following snippet will create a namespace implementation for all sub-directories:

## Linux/ MacOS

```
"Namespace declaration":
{
    "prefix": "name",
    "description": "Creates a new namespace declaration.",
    "body":
    [
        "namespace ${TM_DIRECTORY/^\\/your\\/projects\\/directory(\\/([^\\/]+))(\\/([^\\/]+))?(\\/([^\\/]+))?(\\/([^\\/]+))?(\\/([^\\/]+))?(\\/([^\\/]+))?(\\/([^\\/]+))?(\\/([^\\/]+))?(\\/([^\\/]+))?(\\/([^\\/]+))?/$2${3:+.}$4${5:+.}$6${7:+.}$8${9:+.}$10${11:+.}$12${13:+.}$14${15:+.}$16${17:+.}$18${19:+.}$20/gi}",
        "{",
        "}"
    ]
}
```

## Windows

```
"Namespace declaration":
{
    "prefix": "name",
    "description": "Creates a new namespace declaration.",
    "body":
    [
        "namespace ${TM_DIRECTORY/^c:\\\\your\\\\projects\\\\directory(\\\\([^\\\\]+))(\\\\([^\\\\]+))?(\\\\([^\\\\]+))?(\\\\([^\\\\]+))?(\\\\([^\\\\]+))?(\\\\([^\\\\]+))?(\\\\([^\\\\]+))?(\\\\([^\\\\]+))?(\\\\([^\\\\]+))?(\\\\([^\\\\]+))?/$2${3:+.}$4${5:+.}$6${7:+.}$8${9:+.}$10${11:+.}$12${13:+.}$14${15:+.}$16${17:+.}$18${19:+.}$20/gi}",
        "{",
        "}"
    ]
}
```

## Explanation

1. The snippet matches your base directory and up to ten sub-directories (the first directory is mandatory `(\\/([^\\/]+))`, while all additional nine ones are optional `(\\/([^\\/]+))?`)
2. The namespace directive is then created with the first matched directory
3. For every successful additional sub-directory match, a dot `.` is inserted (`${3:+.}`) with the sub-match of that group (`$4`); for unsuccessful groups, no dot inserted and the sub-match is empty

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It works great for user snippets. If you want to share it with others working on the project, I suggest using WORKSPACE_NAME and RELATIVE_FILEPATH variables to remove dependency on the project path.
`"namespace $WORKSPACE_NAME.${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/([^\\/]+)(\\/([^\\/]+))?(\\/([^\\/]+))?(\\/([^\\/]+))/$1${2:+.}$3${4:+.}$5/i}",`

Answer (score 1):

Found this thread looking for the same answer.

I did not find any of the existing snippet suggestions to generate proper namespaces.
After some trial and error the closest I have gotten, using "[variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables)" and "[placeholder transformation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_placeholdertransform)", is:

```
    "Namespace and Class": {
        "prefix": "nclass",
        "body": [
            "namespace ${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/[\\\\]|\\w+\\.cs$/./g}$1",
            "{",
            "\tpublic class $TM_FILENAME_BASE\n\t{\n\t\t$0\n\t}",
            "}"
        ],
        "description": "Generates namespace and class name"
    }
```

This will generate a namespace from the folder structure in the workspace, and class name using the file name.

There is however an issue with this as it will leave two trailing `..` at end of namespace.
But cursor will stop there, so they can quickly be removed with a `Ctrl + Backspace` and then `tab` again to jump inside body of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one, first it focuses at the end of the namespace to add any additional section. Then it focuses inside the class.

```
"Namespace and Class": {
    "prefix": "nc",
    "body": [
        "namespace $WORKSPACE_NAME$1\n{\n\tpublic class $TM_FILENAME_BASE\n\t{\n\t\t$2\n\t}\n}"
    ],
    "description": "Generates namespace and class name"
}
```